# How can I prevent overload of Mariadb server?

Tags: mysql, mariadb-10.2

I'm running MariaDB 10.2.27 on Ubuntu 16.04 (10 cores, 40 GB RAM).

We have a queued message handling system (using Symfony Messenger) that normally has 20 workers consuming messages from the queue.  These spawn jobs that connect to the database and perform various tasks.

Most of the time it works fine, but occasionally all the workers hit the database simultaneously and the server is slammed.  When this happens, the usage on all 10 cores hits 100% (according to `htop` monitor). The database starts dropping connections and the server is unusable.  This was happening 2 to 3 times a day.  RAM usage is only at 50% and there is no swap usage.

I reduced the number of active workers to six and the problem seems to have gone away.  It's only been two days, but I have not had any problems since then.  I still get an occasional dropped connection, but they are infrequent.

Instead of reducing the number of workers, is there a way to configure MariaDB to "throttle" queries or avoid this kind of overload problem?

Comment: You already know that you can control the concurrency at the application; why do you want to shift that to the database (not that it can do that anyway)? Also, you probably want to figure out what exactly is happening when "the server is slammed"; is it lock contention? I/O saturation? excessive sorts? Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Set `max_connections` to the number of sessions the database can handle. Do the workers create new connections for every time they fetch. Protocols like AMQP handle queues a lot better than MariaDB, even if you just put the primary key in the queue and handle the rest in the database. If you are sticking with MariaDB what are the table structures (`show create table x`) and queries being used along with `explain {query}` for how its executed.

Comment: I'm not using MariaDB as a transport for the messages.  I was doing that originally and considered it might be a problem, so I changed the message transport to Redis.  Unfortunately, it did not make a difference.

I've been monitoring the slow query log, but the problem does correlate to any specific query.  I have a few slow queries in the log, but they are not happening at the time the server locks up.  I've considered lock contention, but I'm not sure how to detect that.  When the server locks up, I can't do anything (like a "SHOW PROCESSLIST").

Comment: I have a mix of clients connecting to the database (not just the messenger workers).  I can't control all the clients, so I would prefer a solution at the DB level.

Comment: [correction to above: "the problem does NOT correlate to any specific query"]

Comment: Are are there patterns of user activity that lead to "slamming"?  Example:  At intermission, everyone runs to the restroom; that slams the restrooms.  Either make bigger restrooms or force them to wait in line.

Comment: I've been trying to figure any patterns, but have been unsuccessful. The problems can occur at any time of the day. The message system handles stuff related to an API to another system, there are no human users.  Basically, I'd like to make the database to "force them to wait in line."

Comment: Maybe install a RDMS monitor tool -> https://webyog.com/product/monyog/ (it is free for 14 days) to find a pattern